# Custom/Style title and body direction in desktop notification (chrome)

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, browser

Using desktop push notification when the title and body written using right-to-left languages like Arabic language, the browser detect the language and change the direction even if dir and lang param not provided in the object the new notification is created for example:

[The title is under the setting icon (this is the current implementation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpoPX.png)

Note: this behavior for windows user and to be more specific just Chrome browser the IOS always work with ltr direction neither if dir and lang provided or not and I try to use the chrome rich notification also it didn't work.

The Question: how I can custom the desktop notification at least show the hole title.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: just to let you know facebook is not using Notifications API in their website .. and Alaa answer seems the right one for your issue

Comment: please see my comment below alaa answer + what Facebook using instead of  Notifications API ?

Comment: Than mean there is another API for desktop notification ?

Comment: you only can see it when you're on the webpage right? then it's some library written in javascript for toast notifications in webpage like https://notifyjs.com

Comment: Actually no, the desktop web notification is displayed as valid session is exist even if the page (tab) is closed so that the problem with the libraries such like Pnotifyjs, it just show on the active tab

Comment: BTW the previous screen shot for Facebook notification is for active tab (opened tab) but when tab is closed the same bug appear

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to customize the Notification Dir as follows:

```
var options = {
  body: 'some text',
  dir: 'ltr'
}

var n = new Notification('Test notification',options);

n.dir // should return 'ltr'
```

Comment: In testing it seemed that the direction was largely determined by the text rather than this parameter. According to the spec this is intended to suggest to the browser how to layout options like actions, but I saw no difference.
from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/display-a-notification

Comment: @Hadeel36 Please share the code you have done so i can help

Comment: let make it simple with simple example 
`new Notification('السلام عليكم ورحمة الله', {body: 'لديك رسالة جديدة', dir: 'ltr', lang: 'en'});` kindly run this in console using windows + chrome browser with taking care that I provide left-to-right direction and the result will be as the above example in the question ... Thank you very much in advance

Comment: @Hadeel36 The notification done by facebook is a custom in browser notification (HTML). It's not using the Notification API.

Comment: BTW the previous screen shot for Facebook notification is for active tab (opened tab) but when tab is closed the same bug appear

Comment: how can I style the text, like bold, italic etc?

Answer (score 0):

according to MDN there's a [`lang option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/lang) to force the language direction, but I'm not sure if this will affect the title

```
// Example from MDN

var options = {
  body: 'Do you like my body?',
  lang: 'en-US'
}

var n = new Notification('Test notification',options);

n.lang // should return 'en-US'
```

Comment: first US is optional, and in the question I write down that even that I provide the wanted direction, the browser detect it, So the browser overwrite this option (dir)